# Як правильно українською називаються числа, що мають додаткові знаки після коми?

Tags: переклад, from-english

В англійській мові існують такі поняття як integer та float. Integer - ціле число. Float (або floating point number) - таке число, яке має додаткові знаки після коми, на приклад: 1,22 або 1,0. Google translate перекладає floating point досить буквально і невірно з точки зору граматики "плаваюча точка" (вже тоді мало б бути: кома, що плаває).

Comment: Ви даєте неправильне означення floating-point-числам. Число, яке має знаки після коми, називається словом _fraction=дріб_ (зокрема _decimal fraction_ = _десятковий дріб_, якщо мова про знаки після коми в десятковому представленні) або _fractional number_ = _дробове число_. А _floating-point number_ (= _число з рухомою комою_) — це навіть не вид числа (це не математичне поняття), це _спосіб представлення_ дробових чисел у пам'яті ЕОМ. Коротко кажучи, **_«таке число, яке має додаткові знаки після коми»_ ≠ _«floating-point number»_**, зокрема, **_«fixed-point number»_ теж має знаки після коми**.

Comment: Тож або Ви питаєте про «floating-point number» (і тоді відповіддю буде щось на зразок «число з рухомою комою»), або Ви питаєте про «таке число, яке має додаткові знаки після коми» (і тоді відповіддю буде щось на зразок «дріб»/«десятковий/двійковий/якийсь дріб»/«дробове число») — але **це різні речі**.

Comment: Дякую @Sasha за допомогу. Поправив моє запитання, зробив дещо точнішим після ваших зауважень 

Comment: Чесно кажучи, я не бачу виправлення того, про що я писав — у Вас запитання все одно написано так, наче floating-point number — це число, яке має додаткові знаки після коми — але це невірно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дивіться [число з рухомою комою](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B7_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%8E):

> Число з рухомою комою — форма представлення дійсних чисел, в якій число зберігається у формі мантиси і показника степеня.
>
> Число з рухомою комою має фіксовану відносну точність, залежну від
>   кількості розрядів мантиси, і змінювану абсолютну. Найбільш часто
>   використовувані представлення затверджено в стандарті IEEE 754.
>   Реалізація математичних операцій з числами з рухомою комою в
>   обчислювальних системах може бути як апаратною, так і програмною.

Comment: Можливо правильно  "не цілі частки/числа"

Comment: Стаття у Вікіпедії сама собою не є авторитетним джерелом. Вона може бути дуже корисною, коли містить посилання на (інші) авторитетні джерела або коли джерел зовсім обмаль і потрібен хоч якийсь поштовх. Але в цьому разі стаття на Вікіпедії, здається, не посилається на жодні україномовні джерела (лише англомовні й російськомовні, що не можуть слугувати обґрунтуванням для українського терміну), тому в цьому випадку краще послатися на [словники](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=floating-point+number&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) або ж додати їх як джерела прямо в статтю на Вікіпедії.

Comment: @Sasha, повністю згоден з вами, але даний термін для української мови є досить новим і до того ж досить технічним, тому не дивно, що його немає в словниках.

Comment: @Ihor, у деяких словниках є, я ж дав посилання у попередньому коментарі.